# How to use JQuery to return HTML page from ASMX web service

Tags: c#, jquery, asmx

I have a ASMX web service, which has the ability to return a string containing HTML code.

Is is possible using JQuery to make a call to this service, get the string response (HTML code), and then using JQuery update the page making the call within a DIV on my page ?

The call to the web service would be made when the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how ASMX web service look like, but in jquery you can just use ajax for this:

```
$.get('service_url', function(response) {
    $('#your_div_id').html(response);
});
```

if ASMX need to POST something you can use post function

```
$.post('service_url', {data: 'someData'}, function(response) {
    $('#your_div_id').html(response);
});
```

if it need string (or xml) then use string instead of object.